# Convert LocaleTimeString Back to Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

Firstly, I convert a datetime to date and time respectively.

```
var d = new Date();
var localeDate = d.toLocaleDateString();
var localeTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

However, when i try to convert it back to date object

```
var convertLocaleDate = new Date(localeDate); // success
var convertLocaleTime = new Date(localeTime); // not a valid date format
```

How can i convert localeTime back to valid date?

Comment: "localTime" will only contain time. So there is no date/month/year. Which date you want time to convert to?

Comment: @hitman4890 i would like to convert the date to epoch date time and retain it as isostring how could it be done

Answer (score 0):

look carefully. You are not converting localeDate back to the original date. The time portion is set to 00:00:00

You cannot achieve the result you are trying for.

new Date() will work for the arguments mentioned below

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

more info here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

giving localeTime as an argument doesn't work because the Date constructor will not know what date/month/year that time is for.

On the other hand localeDate worked because the date/month/year were known and time was set as default to 12am as default